# Ignoring timezone offset when deserializing datetime

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net

I have a datetime in my json formatted like so:

"EventDate": "2017-05-05T11:35:44-07:00",

This file was created in Pacific time, while my server is in eastern time.  When I deserialize this file back into my object, the time is converted to a datetime of 2017-05-05 2:35:44PM.  The problem is that I need the ORIGINAL time, 11:35:44AM.

I have already fixed the problem at the source, but I still need a way to handle all these files that I have.  Is there a way to just deserialize this field to the exact datetime specified without the offset?  I checked DateTimeZoneHandling settings but none of them produced the effect I want.

Comment: @S.Petrosov Not strictly a duplicate in this case in my opinion because this question specifically asks how to deserialise directly without the TZ rather than converting the datetime after the deserialisation.

Comment: You can use a `DateTimeOffset` object type when serializing/deserializing, which will maintain the timezone information, allowing you to display it in whatever timezone you need to. Otherwise, I recommend transmitting it as GMT (`.ToUniversalTime()`) 


Keep in mind, 2017-05-05 14:35:44 -04:00 is the same as 2017-05-05 11:35:44 - 07:00

Comment: @MarkEmbling Yes, now I agree with you. I have tried to modified the DateTime in the class's property setter but  it came up that the value to set is already converted to local time.

Comment: I store datetimes as GMT, and convert it to local time as close to the client as possible (e.g. JS, not the json response)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with AWinkle in the comments above - the best way would be to deserialise as a DateTimeOffset instead of a DateTime - that way, you can display it however you wish.

That said, I used that idea for a possible approach which could be to use a custom JSON type converter to get the timezone-stripping behaviour you're afer. Here's a quick sample I knocked up which seems to do as you ask.

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom converter for returning a DateTime which has been stripped of any time zone information
/// </summary>
public class TimezonelessDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("An exercise for the reader...");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        // We'll make use of Json.NET's own IsoDateTimeConverter so 
        // we don't have to re-implement everything ourselves.
        var isoConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter();

        // Deserialise into a DateTimeOffset which will hold the 
        // time and the timezone from the JSON.
        var withTz = (DateTimeOffset)isoConverter.ReadJson(reader, typeof(DateTimeOffset), existingValue, serializer);

        // Return the DateTime component. This will be the original 
        // datetime WITHOUT timezone information.
        return withTz.DateTime;
    }
}
```

This can then be used like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Nonsense class just to represent your data. You'd implement the JsonConverter
/// attribute on your own model class.
/// </summary>
public class Sample {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TimezonelessDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
}

//
// And a sample of the actual deserialisation...
///

var json = "{ \"EventDate\": \"2017-05-05T11:35:44-07:00\" }";
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
};
var deserialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sample>(json, settings);
Console.WriteLine(deserialised.EventDate);
```

This will output `05/05/2017 11:35:44`.

This is definitely not the most robust approach and I'm almost certain there are things I've not accounted for - and it probably ought to be bit more thoroughly tested to make sure there isn't some horrible side effect. However hopefully it's a starting point of a possible solution and points you in the right direction.

P.S. if you also serialise back to JSON, you'll need to implement the `WriteJson` method too. I didn't do that one, so right now it only goes one direction.