# How to deserialize string DateTimeOffset to DateTime by JsonConvert without any time conversion

Tags: c#, json.net

Code

```
 Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now);
```

Returns 7/25/2023 6:32:37 PM +02:00 - So its my LocalTime(6:32PM) + Offset (Loc-UTC);

[image]
When deserialize DateTimeOffset string to DateTime - hours are added - how to ignore that?
It's .net core 2.1.

```
    class Test
    {
        public DateTime departure;
    }
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>("{\"departure\":\"2023-07-25T18:32:37+02:00\"}",
                new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified,
                    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
                });

            Console.WriteLine(testObj.departure);
            //> 7/25/2023 6:32:37 PM OK 
        }
    }
```

But when I specify

```
"{\"departure\":\"2023-07-25T18:32:37+00:00\"}"
```

I'm receiving

```
7/25/2023 8:32:37 PM
```

I want just 18:32:37

I want to achieve just local time from deserialization.
I've tried different settings in JsonSerializerSettings and read doc -- there stands
DateParseHandling.None "Date formatted strings are not parsed to a date type and are read as strings"

Please advice.

Comment: Why don't keep "+02:00" if it is ok for you?

Comment: The `+02:00` is the offset part of `DateTimeOffset`.  If you don't want to see an offset, why not use `DateTime` instead?

Comment: From the docs for `Unspecified` - _"If a string is being converted to "DateTime", convert to a local time if a time zone is specified."_, `8:32:37` is the time you have tried to parse in your local timezone. If `7/25/2023 6:32:37 ` is ok then `8:32:37` should be ok also.

Comment: Thanks for responses so far.
My code is just an example, in real my application has type DateTime - this is example it's Test class. From external Api (I think it's bug) once I'm receiving DateTime and another time DateTimeFormat (as json)- it's hardcoded string in example.

@Serge - my app operates on  DateTime type - I don't need offset infos.

Comment: You are effectively modifying the value of the `DateTime` by ignoring the offset, which as far as I know Json.NET will not do out of the box.  Thus you'll need a custom converter.  Does the one from [Ignoring timezone offset when deserializing datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44166565) by Mark Embling do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @dbc you direct me to solution with custom converter.

```
 public class DateTimeOffsetToDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    //objectType - Type that json is going to be parsed to, here: [Test], [DateTime] 
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
    }

    //method with custom Parse
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            var dateString = (string)reader.Value;
            if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(dateString, out DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset))
            {
                return dateTimeOffset.DateTime;
            }
        }

        throw new JsonSerializationException($"Unexpected token or invalid DateTimeOffset format: {reader.TokenType}");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

With following usage:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now);

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeOffsetToDateTimeConverter());
        settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified;
        settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;

        //1 Test DateTimeOffset
        var testObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>("{\"departure\":\"2023-07-25T18:31:37+02:00\"}", settings);
        Console.WriteLine(testObj.departure);
        //Without convert 7/25/2023 8:31:37 PM - I wanted origin 18:31:37

        //2 Test DateTimeOffset +00
        var testObj2 =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>("{\"departure\":\"2023-07-25T18:32:37+00:00\"}", settings);
        Console.WriteLine(testObj2.departure);

        //3 Test DateTime 
        var testObj3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>("{\"departure\":\"2023-07-25T18:33:37\"}", settings);
        Console.WriteLine(testObj3.departure);
    }
```

That produces:

```
7/25/2023 6:31:37 PM 
7/25/2023 6:32:37 PM
7/25/2023 6:33:37 PM
```